# Proof that CSL ⊊ REC

Tags: turing-machines, proof-techniques, context-sensitive

I'm trying to prove that a context sensitive language ⊊ Turing-acceptable language.
I was thinking of working out the complement of the language $A$, where $A$ consists of all words $w$ such that $M_w$ is a 1-NTM that accepts the input $w$ without leaving the input area.

Unfortunately, I can’t figure out how to really prove it.

Comment: Your attempt seems to be missing something. How was the language $A$ supposed to be defined?

Comment: The context-sensitive languages are those accepted by nondeterministic Turing machines in linear space. Hence you can use the nondeterministic space hierarchy theorem to solve your question (as well as many other hierarchy theorems).

Comment: Would building this $A = \{w ∈ \{0, 1\}^+\}$ ∣ Mw is a 1-NTM that accepts the input wˆ without leaving the input area}. be enough to proof ? How would this Turing machine look like

Comment: Why where you thinking of this particular $A$?

Comment: To check for the complement of it , do u have any better suggestions or an easier way to prove that CSL is a subset of recursive languages ?

Comment: It follows directly from the nondeterministic space hierarchy theorem, whose proof is along the lines of your $A$.

Comment: I feel like I’m so close to the answer but I just can’t grasp it nor articulate it correctly

Comment: @Mago12243 if there is a linear bounded TM $M_p$ for $\bar{A}$ what happens if you run it on itself?
(there are just two cases to check;  $p\in\bar{A}$ and $p\notin\bar{A}$)